# F# Generic constraint to have one generic type inherit from another

Tags: generics, f#, type-constraints

In C# it is straightforward to define a generic class when one generic parameter inherits from another, e.g.:

```
public class MyClass<TClass, TInterface> where TClass : class, TInterface
{
}
```

This is used to "force" the class `TClass` to implement the interface `TInterface`. I want to do the same in F# and surprisingly it does not seem to work. For example, the following code:

```
type Startup<'S, 'I when 'I : not struct and 'S : not struct and 'S :> 'I>() =
    member _.x = 0
```

results in `FS0663` - `This type parameter has been used in a way that constrains it to always be ''I when 'I : not struct'`. I wonder if the generic structure similar to C# above can be implemented in F#.

At this point one may wonder why do I need that? Here is why. I want to have a generic F# interop with `CoreWCF`like:

```
open CoreWCF
open CoreWCF.Configuration
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

module Startup =

    type Startup<'S, 'I when 'I : not struct and 'S : not struct>() =
        let createServiceModel (builder : IServiceBuilder) = 
            builder
                .AddService<'S>()
                .AddServiceEndpoint<'S, 'I>(new BasicHttpBinding(), "/basichttp")
                .AddServiceEndpoint<'S, 'I>(new NetTcpBinding(), "/nettcp")
            |> ignore

        member _.ConfigureServices(services : IServiceCollection) =
            do services.AddServiceModelServices() |> ignore

        member _.Configure(app : IApplicationBuilder, env : IHostingEnvironment) =
            do app.UseServiceModel(fun builder -> createServiceModel builder) |> ignore
```

which then can be used as follows:

```
open System.Net
open CoreWCF.Configuration
open Microsoft.AspNetCore
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core

module Builder =
    let CreateWebHostBuilder() : IWebHostBuilder =
        let applyOptions (options : KestrelServerOptions) =
            let address : IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.89")
            let port = 8080
            let endPoint : IPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(address, port)
            options.Listen(endPoint)

        WebHost
            .CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseKestrel(fun options -> applyOptions options)
            .UseNetTcp(8808)
            .UseStartup<Startup<EchoWcfService, IEchoWcfService>>()
```

where `EchoWcfService`, of course, implement interface `IEchoWcfService`. The problem with `Startup` without generic constraint that `'S` implements `'I` as above is that nothing precludes writing something like: `.UseStartup<Startup<EchoWcfService, string>>()`, which will, of course, blow up at runtime.

**Update**

Given the comments and the references I tried to address the issue in a mixed F# + C# way. So, we can easily create a generic class in C#:

```
public class WcfStartup<TService, TInterface>
    where TService : class
    //where TService : class, TInterface
{
    private void CreateServiceModel(IServiceBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            .AddService<TService>()
            .AddServiceEndpoint<TService, TInterface>(new BasicHttpBinding(), "/basichttp")
            .AddServiceEndpoint<TService, TInterface>(new NetTcpBinding(), "/nettcp");
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) =>
        services.AddServiceModelServices();

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) =>
        app.UseServiceModel(CreateServiceModel);
}
```

and then change `.UseStartup<Startup<EchoWcfService, IEchoWcfService>>()` into `.UseStartup<WcfStartup<EchoWcfService, IEchoWcfService>>()` after referencing C# project with that class.

Now, if I comment `where TService : class` and uncomment `where TService : class, TInterface` then F# project will no longer compile with `This expression was expected to have type 'EchoWcfService' but here has type 'IEchoWcfService'`, which is basically the same as the "original" F# compile error but just with a different flavor.

**I'd call it a bug in F# compiler**...

Comment: A minimal reproduction is `type T<'A, 'B when 'A :> 'B>() = class end` and it's worth posting on the dotnet/fsharp repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from the F# spec:

*New constraints of the form type :> 'b are solved again as type = 'b.*

There are some popular F# language suggestions that aim to solve this, see:

https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/255

https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/162