# F# type constraint error trying to write a type map

Tags: f#

I am trying to write an API on top of a C# library. The C# code has a dictionary from types to values that I would like to represent using immutable data structures.

However, I am having trouble writing the type constraints correctly:

```ml
open System

// System.Type cannot be used a map key
// TODO: Is this enough data to form a key?
type ComparableType = 
  {
    AssemblyQualifiedName : string
  }

type TypeMap<'t> = 
  private 
  | TypeMap of Map<ComparableType, 't>

module TypeMap = 

  let private innerMap = 
    function
    | TypeMap m -> m
  
  let empty () = 
    TypeMap Map.empty

  // Here is the problem line!  
  let add<'t, 'v when 'v :> 't> (v : 'v) (m : TypeMap<'t>) =        
    let t = typeof<'v>

    let k = 
      {
        AssemblyQualifiedName = t.AssemblyQualifiedName
      }

    m
    |> innerMap
    |> Map.add k (v :> 't)
    |> TypeMap
```

Error:

> Invalid constraint: the type used for the constraint is sealed, which means the constraint could only be satisfied by at most one solution

Comment: I do not think F# can handle a generic constraint like that. Also, it wont let you do a coertion to an undetermined type. Your best bet is to use `box v` instead of `(v :> 't)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a limitation of the F# compiler. In this code, it will assume that `'A = 'B`:

```ml
type T<'A, 'B when 'A :> 'B>() = class end
```

The work-around is to make the type parameter of `TypeMap<'t>` concrete. Unfortunately this requires lots of boiler-plate, but it is a solution I can live with:

```ml
type FooTypeMap = 
  private 
  | FooTypeMap of Map<ComparableType, Foo>

module FooTypeMap = 

  let private innerMap = 
    function
    | FooTypeMap m -> m

// etc...
```

There is a request for change here: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/255

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64113104/1256041

Answer (score 0):

I do not think F# can handle a generic constraint like that. Also, it wont let you do a coertion to an undetermined type. Your best bet is to use `box v` instead of `(v :> 't)`

Like this:

```
type ComparableType = 
{
    AssemblyQualifiedName : string
}

type TypeMap = 
private 
| TypeMap of Map<ComparableType, obj>

module TypeMap = 

let private innerMap = 
    function
    | TypeMap m -> m

let empty () = 
    TypeMap Map.empty

let inline add (v : 'v) (m : TypeMap) =        
    let t = typeof< 'v>

    let k = 
    {
        AssemblyQualifiedName = t.AssemblyQualifiedName
    }

    m
    |> innerMap
    |> Map.add k (box v)
    |> TypeMap

let inline get< ^v>  (m : TypeMap) : ^v =
    let t = typeof<'v>

    let k = 
    {
        AssemblyQualifiedName = t.AssemblyQualifiedName
    }

    (innerMap m).[k] 
    |> unbox
```